# Matplotlib plt.fill_between 'isinfinite' error

Tags: matplotlib

I have this code:

```
g1 = plt.plot(centers[0],'-',label=u'Group 1',color='#1f77b4')
g1_max = plt.plot(centers[0]+max_g1,'-',color='#1f77b4',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(range(len(g1)),g1,g1_max,facecolor='#1f77b4',alpha=0.5)
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Any clue why?
Thanks

Comment: See [mcve] and provide one here such that people are able to reproduce this. As it stands we have no idea about the variables in use here and hence you can get almost any error from the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

plt.fill_between is used wrongly here, x, y1 and y2 must be lists instead of generators or plot objects (see https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html).
Probably the following will work:

```
import numpy as np

g1 = plt.plot(centers[0],'-',label=u'Group 1',color='#1f77b4')
g1_max = plt.plot(centers[0]+max_g1,'-',color='#1f77b4',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(np.arange(len(g1)),centers[0],centers[0]+g1_max,facecolor='#1f77b4',alpha=0.5)
```